# Wordpress | Unable to create new post in Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I created an CPT with this code in `functions.php`
`

```
// Register Custom Post Type
function qrmenu() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'QR Menüler', 'Post Type General Name', 'egmenu' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'QR Menü', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'egmenu' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Post Types', 'egmenu' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Post Type', 'egmenu' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Item Archives', 'egmenu' ),
        'attributes'            => __( 'Item Attributes', 'egmenu' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'egmenu' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Items', 'egmenu' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Item', 'egmenu' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'egmenu' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Item', 'egmenu' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Item', 'egmenu' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Item', 'egmenu' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Item', 'egmenu' ),
        'view_items'            => __( 'View Items', 'egmenu' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Item', 'egmenu' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'egmenu' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'egmenu' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'egmenu' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'egmenu' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'egmenu' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'egmenu' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'egmenu' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'egmenu' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'egmenu' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'egmenu' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'egmenu' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'QR Menü', 'egmenu' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'trackbacks', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes', 'post-formats' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'menu_icon'             => 'site',
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => false,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => true,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
        'show_in_rest'          => true,
        'rest_base'             => 'm',
        'rest_controller_class' => 'm',
    );
    register_post_type( 'm', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'qrmenu', 0 );
```

It's add the CPT but when i try to create a post in that CTP, it gives me blank white page.
There is one `404` page in connection and it's `http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/m/11?context=edit&_locale=user`
The error response is `rest_no_route`
HTML is loading but editor don't.
How can i fix this?

Thanks for help!

NOTE: I'm using Wordpress 6.0.1

Comment: Did you re-save the permalinks?

Comment: yes, i did and i used `flush_rewrite_rules()` too

Comment: Did you create `rest_controller_class` "m" like you say?

Comment: No i didn't but i noticed samething. I tried to use CPT UI plugin and it was okay. When i tried to add new post from frontend with `wp_insert_post` function, it adds but when i pusblish it and open it, it gives me `404` again. BUT when i create a new post manually from panel, its works. I guess `wp_insert_post` is buggy... This this the code:

Comment: `$postId = "".getUserCompanyId() . $menuId."";

$m = array(
    'insert_id' => $postId,
    'post_title' => $menuName . ' | ' . $postId,
    'post_name' => ''.$postId.'',
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'draft',
    'post_author' => get_current_user_id(),
    'post_type' => 'm',
);

$insert = wp_insert_post( $m );`